# Wordpress:"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Tags: php, wordpress

A few hours ago I installed wordpress on my localhost, but when I connect to it with my browser an Error is displayed

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

My PHP version is `7.0` and I know that I have installed `MySQLi`.
The DataBase for Wordpress is set. I create the user and the password.

A few minutes ago I installed a plugin which is supposed to solve the problem, but when I refresh the page it goes in blank

Comment: did you install php-mysql? or php-pdo?

Comment: What's the platform you're running on? I'd say either checking php from the command line (`php --m`) or using `phpinfo();` to make sure the extension is in fact loading properly. Have you restarted your httpd or php service since installing the extension?

Comment: I wrote the  command and the terminal display this:

Comment: [PHP Modules]
Core
date
filter
hash
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Reflection
session
SPL
standard
zlib

[Zend Modules]